# Check forEach last iteration firebase to avoid autocomplete duplicates

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, autocomplete

I am trying to create a autocomplete search box for which I have the following firebase code, which I call on onkeyup of an input box:

```
function($scope){
 $scope.searchResult = [];
firebaseDb.ref("event")
    .orderByChild("eventName")
    .startAt(scope.searchinput)
    .endAt(scope.searchinput + "\uf8ff")
    .on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                $scope.searchResult.push(childSnapshot.key);
                //if last iteration clear $scope.searchResult to avoid duplicates
        });
    });
}
}
```

I will be binding a `div` in html to `searchResult` model to display the suggestion . As stated in the comment in code I need to clear `searchResult` at the end of last iteration. I cant clear it outside the firebase callback function because due to asynchronous nature , my `searchResult` array could get cleared in between search.

How do I find that a particular iteration is the last  ? Also any other approach to avoid duplicates, while user types a name in search box, in `searchResult` array are welcome